# What are typical "theta" values for an LDA topic model with k = 50 or 100?

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-models

I have performed LDA using the topicmodels package in R. When I was inspecting my theta values for each document in the corpus, I noticed that the average max theta, or in other words, the average highest probability that the document is in a certain topic, was ~9%. This seems very low, but I am unable to find any literature that would give me an idea of what it should be around.

In case I am doing something else wrong, here are the parameters I am using:

```
    burnin <- 1000
    iter <- 1000
    keep <- 10
    k<-100 
    models <- LDA(dtm2, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(burnin = burnin,        
    iter = iter, keep = keep))

    phi <- posterior(models)$terms %>% as.matrix
    theta <- posterior(models)$topics %>% as.matrix`
```